# On Keypress event reading multiple keys?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, eventhandler

So I want to make a method that reads the keypress event and then records the keystroke into a string.  The idea is that the string contains either a leading "R" or "L" followed by 2 integer numbers.  However, when I display the "MoveDist" string variable in my MoveBox method, it always is the same keypress repeated 3 times, rather than re-polling the keyboard after each stroke.  For example, when I run the debug and enter an "R" the program crashes because the input string immediately becomes "rrr".  Anyone have a solution?

```
void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{

    String input = "";

        if (e.KeyChar == 108)
        {
            input = "l";
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == 114)
        {
            input = "r";
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar >= 48 && e.KeyChar <= 57)
        {
            int charPress = e.KeyChar - 48;
            input = input + charPress.ToString();
        }

    Form1_MoveBox(input);

}

void Form1_MoveBox(String newInput)
{
    String input = "";
    while (input.Length <= 3)
    {
        input = input + newInput;
    }
    String moveDist = input.Substring(1, 3);

    MessageBox.Show(moveDist);

    int distance = Int32.Parse(moveDist);

    if (input.Substring(0, 1) == "l")
    {
        int x = panel1.Location.X - distance;
        int y = panel1.Location.Y;
        panel1.Location = new Point(x, y);
        panel1.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (input.Substring(0, 1) == "r")
    {
        int x = panel1.Location.X + distance;
        int y = panel1.Location.Y;
        panel1.Location = new Point(x, y);
        panel1.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: There are a lot of bugs in this code.  Start fixing it by moving the *input* variable outside of the KeyPress event handler so its value is retained between key presses.  Spend time practicing the use of the debugger so you can diagnose these kind of bugs yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `KeyUp` instead of `KeyPress` because generally, you should handle the `KeyUp` event in your application. Actions should not be initiated in the UI until after the user releases the key.

Order ofevents firing in this situation is

1. KeyDown (one time)
2. KeyPress (until the key is pressed and based on OS settings for delay and repeat rate of keyboard)
3. KeyUp (one time)

you can prevent `KeyPress` from firing multiple time when the key is hold by the user a long time by setting a boolean to true in `KeyDown` and then set it to false on `KeyUp` but the good point about `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` is that they fire just once no matter how long the user hold the key pressed and you can avoid "rrrrrrrrrrr".

another benefit of using `KeyUp` is that you have many additional information about the user input like if the Alt, Ctrl or Shift is pressed or the `Control` of the event and the `KeyCode` property that you can use it and compare it with `Keys` to avoid using some sort of `e.KeyChar == 108` in your code and make it more readable like `e.KeyCode == Keys.R`.

Answer (score 0):

The key press event also triggers if you hold down the key. So if you hit the r key it will most likely fire multiple times. It is better to use the keydown event for this one. It wil only fire once when you press the r key but won't continue to fire if you hold the key.